# Debugging .NET Core Application in the Docker container using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to set up a development environment entirely using docker containers so that I don't have to install dependencies on the developer machines. Is there a way to use visual studio (not visual studio code) to debug .net core application that is running in the container?

#### Steps I Followed

1. I created an image that has all the dependencies like SDKs and packages in it.
2. I am mounting the code using volumes into the container so that I can make changes to the code that is on the host machine. (I am also doing "watch" to restart the app when changes are detected).

#### Desired Behaviour

Because the dependencies are inside the container, the visual studio is not able to detect those dependencies (it shows red squiggly lines in the code). How do I make the visual studio linter detect those dependencies?

Comment: Sure you can debug your containerized apps using VS, did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/edit-and-refresh?view=vs-2022)? But the red lines you are talking about are not about debugging, it's about compiling. So your question is not clear